# Removing author's name from abstract

Tags: abstract

I'm using this template: https://www.overleaf.com/5498197zgcfjy#/17625707/

How can I (modify the document to) leave out the name of the author in the abstract?

Answer (score 2):

Simply delete lines 72 and 107...

Comment: You mean 72 and 108? But the "by" stays in the abstract.

Comment: It's probably not the best way but `\providecaptionname{american,australian,british,canadian,english,newzealand,UKenglish,USenglish}{\byname}{}` works.

Comment: @JérômeDequeker Where should I replace this in the doc?

Comment: Copy/Paste this line just before the `\begin{document}`

Answer (score 1):

The document class - `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls` - inserts a large preamble when you call `\begin{abstract}`. Here's the definition of that (lines 293-316):

```
\newenvironment{abstract}{
    \checktoopen
    \tttypeout{\abstractname}
    \null\vfil
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \begin{center}
    {\normalsize \MakeUppercase{\univname} \par} % University name in capitals
    \bigskip
    {\huge\textit{\abstractname} \par}
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize \facname \par} % Faculty name
    {\normalsize \deptname \par} % Department name
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize \degreename\par} % Degree name
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize\bfseries \@title \par} % Thesis title
    \medskip
    {\normalsize \byname{} \authorname \par} % Author name
    \bigskip
    \end{center}
}
{
  \vfil\vfil\vfil\null
}
```

This is something you could modify to reach your goals. Specifically, deleting lines 309-310:

```
    \medskip
    {\normalsize \byname{} \authorname \par} % Author name
```

should leave you with:

[image]

Comment: On the link there's no line 293-316. Should I add the code between `\begin{abstract}` and `\end{abstract}` ?

Comment: @faf: Click on "Project" in the top bar, which will expose the files associated with the project in a tree on the left. The click on `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls`. In that file you should be able to see what I show above. If it is not visible, then the project you shared may have been altered and you should start anew.

Comment: Personally, I do not advise to modify a cls file. For example, when your latex distribution is updated, your modified files are overwritten. And I like to have an update distribution to be able to use all the new features. That's why I recommend to do the modifications in your own tex file, like @Tom and I did.

Comment: @JérômeDequeker: This is a template from an *online* editor and may be (is?) unique to Overleaf. So "your distribution" will never have this `.cls` as part of it.

Comment: @Werner. You're right. It was not needed here. But I like to take good habits.